# Is there a policy for reviewing new tags or proposing existing or better alternatives?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there a policy for reviewing newly added tags or proposing existing or better alternatives?

It is to find out if there is a policy of choosing other tags if there is a more popular tag related to the question, so better to relate the newly asked question to closely related questions.

Comment: Not beyond posting a question about that tag on meta. Notice that only users with 1500 reputation can create new tags in the first place.

Comment: @rene Thanks. FWIW I added a new tag, `git-refspec` on SO

Comment: And why did you do that? What do you want to know? Can you elaborate on that in the question?

Comment: The tag was for SO not for meta.SO and I have updated the comment to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you've created the tag, it might actually be useful for you to add some details to it's description to aid the community:

[git-refspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-refspec)

Also, for your reference, the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) provides the following information about tag creation and usage:

> **What happens when a new tag is created?**
>
> The new tag will now be available for all other community members to
>   use, without needing the new tag privilege. It will also show up in
>   the moderator tools new tag report.
>
> However, note that:
>
> - on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from
>     the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6
>     month period.
> - meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag
>     on a question, are not allowed.
>
> Please create new tags responsibly!